# Want to add image to my program

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, graphics2d

The class I have show you it had call by another class that class extend JPanel, And this class use for create Rectangle and have property when it collision with another. And I want to know how to add image to the Rectangle. If the graphics2D can't add the image I want to change it to label or something it work. pls guide me

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Entity{

private int x;
private int y;
private int size;
private BufferedImage image;

    public Entity(int x){
        this.size = x;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setPosition(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Rectangle getBound(){
        return new Rectangle(x ,y,size, size);
    }

    public boolean isCollid(Entity e){
        if (e == this) return false;
        return getBound().intersects(e.getBound());
    }

    public void render(Graphics2D g2d){
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Graphics#drawImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage-java.awt.Image-int-int-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-) - Seriously, you shouldn't be asking this type of question without first reading through the Docs and attempting some research - it's not like this hasn't be asked and answered copious times before

Comment: I mean, there's even a [tutorial on the subject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html)

Answer (score 0):

well, first you have to create a file under "src" called "resources". and then, put all the images you want to access in that file (resources). Then, import ImageIcon:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
```

next, create a new ImageIcon with the desired image:

```
ImageIcon name = new ImageIcon("src/resources/[image name here, with the ".png"]");
```

finally, create a new JLabel with the icon:

```
JLabel name = new JLabel([ImageIcon name]);
```

then do whatever you want with this new JLabel. If the JLabel doesn't show up, or it just stays in the middle and you can't change the x/y position, alert me and I will tell you. Hope this helps.